# Show surrounding lines of a specific line via linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line

Right now I am running:

```
head -1274954 /path/to/dump.sql | tail -1
```

This shows me one line, I'd like to see 10 lines above and 10 lines below it.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
$ head -1274964 /path/to/dump.sql | tail -20
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Check `$ man head`

```
NAME
   head - output the first part of files
```

Check `$ man tail`

```
NAME
   tail - output the last part of files
```

You are piping `(|)` output of head command to tail command.
That's why it is printing last line from first 1274954 lines.

```
$ head -1274964 /path/to/dump.sql | tail -20
```

It will generate output upto lines 1274964 and pipe it to tail command which will print 20 lines which are at the bottom of your output of head command.